# Tensorflow cost function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, cost-based-optimizer

I have an input dataset x with shape (10,1000), 10 inputs and 1000 lines and a output y with (1,1000), 1 output and 1000 lines.

The cost function I defined is

```
cost = tf.square(Y - prediction, name="cost")
```

The prediction is a single predicted output value and Y is the placeholder of output values. I used the code below to get the value of cost.

```
cost_value = sess.run(cost, feed_dict ={ X: x, Y : y })
```

Then the output cost function value is a (1000,1000) matrix since the feed of Y is a (1,1000) vector. 
The question is how could I make a cost function that calculate the cost in a number instant of a matrix without looping all the inputs line by line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.reduce_sum(cost)` will sum all of the values in the matrix.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_sum

Answer (score 2):

Also `tf.reduce_sum(cost)` will do what you want, I think it is better to use [`tf.reduce_mean()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reduce_mean). Here are a few reasons why:

- you get consistent loss independent of your matrix size. On average you will get reduce_sum 4 times bigger for a two times bigger matrix
- less chances you will get `nan` by overflowing